# Java REST WS with DB

Tags: java, rest, connection-pool

I want to get the feedback this code about the best practice I should follow and if I am using the connection pooling properly.

I have classes as follows:

`DAOConnectionFactory`- to fetch pooled connections from the Datasource
`WatcherService`- the REST WS
`WatcherDAO`- called by `WatcherService` to insert data in DB
`Watcher`- this is bean class for Watcher

Based on some other reviews I made the methods in the `WatcherDAO` class as static and the `perparedstatement` and `connection` as local variables.

**Context.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/PresenceRepository"/-->
<Context path="/PresenceRepository">
    <Resource auth="Container" 
              cachePrepStmts="true" 
              defaultAutoCommit="true" 
              driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
              factory="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariJNDIFactory" 
              global="jdbc/presencedb" 
              jdbcUrl="jdbc:mysql://192.168.253.128/opensips" 
              maxWaitMillis="10000" maximumPoolSize="20" 
              name="jdbc/presencedb" 
              password="root" 
              prepStmtCacheSize="30" 
              prepStmtCacheSqlLimit="500" 
              removeAbandoned="true" 
              removeAbandonedTimeout="300" 
              type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
              username="root"/>
</Context>
```

**Connection class**

```java
public class DAOConnectionFactory {

    private static final org.slf4j.Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DAOConnectionFactory.class);
    private static final String databaseJNDI = "jdbc/presencedb";
    private static DataSource dataSource = null;
    private DAOConnectionFactory(){}
    static {

        try {
            dataSource = (DataSource) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env/" + databaseJNDI);
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            logger.error("Error while creating datasource.", e);
        }

    }

    protected static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {

        return dataSource.getConnection();
    }

    protected static void closeConnection(Connection connection, Statement statement, ResultSet resultSet) {
        if (resultSet != null) {
            try {
                resultSet.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                logger.error("Error while closing resultset.", e);
            }
        }
        if (statement != null) {
            try {
                statement.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                logger.error("Error while closing statement.", e);
            }
        }
        if (connection != null) {
            try {
                connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                logger.error("Error while closing connection.", e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Exposed REST**

```java
@Path("/watcher")
public class WatcherService {

    private static final org.slf4j.Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WatcherService.class);

    @GET
    @Path("/presentity/{presentityURI}")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Response getWatcherForPresentityByStatus(@Context UriInfo uriInfo) {

        MultivaluedMap<String, String> queryParameters = uriInfo.getQueryParameters();
        MultivaluedMap<String, String> pathParameters = uriInfo.getPathParameters();

        List<Watchers> watchersList;
        GenericEntity< List< Watchers>> entity;
        try {
            if (uriInfo.getQueryParameters().containsKey("status") && uriInfo.getQueryParameters().containsKey("event")) {
                watchersList = WatcherDAO.findByPresentityAndStatus(queryParameters, pathParameters);
            } else {
                watchersList = WatcherDAO.findByPresentityAndEvent(queryParameters, pathParameters);
            }
            Response.ResponseBuilder response;

            if (!watchersList.isEmpty()) {
                entity = new GenericEntity<List<Watchers>>(watchersList) {
                };
                response = Response.ok(entity);
            } else { 
                response = Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).entity("Requested resource could not be found.");
            }    
            return response.build();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error while fetching watcher details for presentity {}.", pathParameters.getFirst("presentityURI"), e);
            return Response.status(500).entity("Server was unable to process the request.").build();
        }
    }

}
```

**Interface to DB**

```java
public class WatcherDAO {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WatcherDAO.class);

    private static final String SELECT_BY_PRES_AND_STATUS = "select watcher_username,watcher_domain from watchers where presentity_uri=? AND event=? AND status=?";

    //Watcher Table: Primary key = id.
    //Unique index: presentity_uri,watcher_username,event,watcher_domain


    public static List<Watchers> findByPresentityAndStatus(MultivaluedMap<String, String> queryParameters, MultivaluedMap<String, String> pathParameters) throws SQLException {
        Connection connection = null;
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
        int index = 0;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        try {
            connection = DAOConnectionFactory.getConnection();
            preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(SELECT_BY_PRES_AND_STATUS);

            preparedStatement.setObject(++index, pathParameters.getFirst("presentityURI"));
            preparedStatement.setObject(++index, queryParameters.getFirst("event"));
            preparedStatement.setObject(++index, queryParameters.getFirst("status"));

            rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            Watchers watchers;
            List<Watchers> watchersList = new ArrayList<>();
            while (rs.next()) {
                watchers = new Watchers();
                watchers.setWatcherUsername(rs.getString(1));
                watchers.setWatcherDomain(rs.getString(2));
                watchersList.add(watchers);
            }
            logger.debug("Query returned {} results.", watchersList.size());
            return watchersList;
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            logger.error("Error while fetching watcher for presentity {}.", pathParameters.getFirst("presentityURI"));
            throw ex;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error("Error while fetching watcher for presentity {}.", pathParameters.getFirst("presentityURI"));
            throw ex;
        } finally {
            DAOConnectionFactory.closeConnection(connection, preparedStatement, rs);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    MultivaluedMap<String, String> queryParameters = uriInfo.getQueryParameters();
    MultivaluedMap<String, String> pathParameters = uriInfo.getPathParameters();

    List<Watchers> watchersList;
    try {
        if (uriInfo.getQueryParameters().containsKey("status") && uriInfo.getQueryParameters().containsKey("event")) {
            watchersList = WatcherDAO.findByPresentityAndStatus(queryParameters, pathParameters);
        } else {
            watchersList = WatcherDAO.findByPresentityAndEvent(queryParameters, pathParameters);
        }
```

That part should really be a separate function. You're doing all that effort just to get `watchersList`.

Similarily, `entity` doesn't need to be a local variable, as you're never doing anything to it.

```
@GET
@Path("/presentity/{presentityURI}")
@Produces("application/json")
public Response getWatcherForPresentityByStatus(@Context UriInfo uriInfo) {

    try {
        List<Watchers> watchersList = getWatchersList(uriInfo.getQueryParameters(), uriInfo.getPathParameters());
        Response.ResponseBuilder response;

        if (!watchersList.isEmpty()) {
            response = Response.ok(new GenericEntity<List<Watchers>>(watchersList) {});
        } else { 
            response = Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).entity("Requested resource could not be found.");
        }    
        return response.build();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error while fetching watcher details for presentity {}.", pathParameters.getFirst("presentityURI"), e);
        return Response.status(500).entity("Server was unable to process the request.").build();
    }
}

private List<Watchers> getWatchersList(MultivaluedMap<String, String> queryParameters, MultivaluedMap<String, String> pathParameters) throws Exception {
    if (queryParameters.containsKey("status") && queryParameters.containsKey("event")) {
        return WatcherDAO.findByPresentityAndStatus(queryParameters, pathParameters);
    } else {
        return WatcherDAO.findByPresentityAndEvent(queryParameters, pathParameters);
    }
}
```